# How to add more string data to an existing (filled) column

Tags: mysql, sql

e.g.

### Table A (id - auto increment)

```
id  labels        names
1   a1,a3,b4      a1
2   a2,b5         a2
3   a1,b4         a2
```

**What i want is to update `names` column such as "existing_names_data + ', B'" where labels like %b4%**

I know following query works with integers not with strings, but i tried and failed anyways -

```
update TableA set names=names+ " B" where labels like '%b4%'
```

Is there any such query for **strings**?
Or, what should I do to get desired output?

**Desired Output**

```
id  labels        names
1   a1,a3,b4      a1, B
2   a2,b5         a2
3   a1,b4         a2, B
```

Thanks. Regards,

Comment: Use the `CONCAT()` function instead of +

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) function:

```
UPDATE foo SET bar = CONCAT(bar, ' B') WHERE foobar = 'barfoo';
```

---

..that said, you should *really* just use a different relational table and normalize your data rather than add comma/semicolon/space seperated columns.

Consider the following structure:

`messages`:

- `id`
- `name`

`message_labels`:

- `id`
- `message_id` (`JOIN message_labels ON message_labels.message_id = message.id`)
- `label`

`message_names`:

- `id`
- `message_id` (`JOIN message_names ON message_names.message_id = message.id`)
- `name`

Answer (score 0):

For Strings you may use the || to concat strings:

```
update TableA set names=names ||' '|| 'B' where labels like '%b4%'
```